# i can't use the azure ad sample, rebuild error

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

i clone the active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web(https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web) demo from azure ad code samples in vs2015, rebuild the solution , but have 26 errors, i have tried update ADAL library to the newest version , but seems nothing happend , i haven't find similar error in issues in github issues,anything i missed ? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your steps and could reproduce your error,you could try to reinstall the ADAL library(Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory) and Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient library , now it works on my side , that demo uses the Azure AD Graph API client library .Please have a try and tell me whether it works.

Comment: thanks for your quickly response ,I tried and it works now!

Comment: i have another question about this code sample, please help me,link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830016/failed-to-acquire-token-silently-as-no-token-was-found-in-the-cache-call-method