# Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I use this code sample :https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web , i know this code sample is using client library , but if i want to perfrom a query (use httpclient) directly use api calls ,i used below code to get the access token from cache :

```
 string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value; 
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID)); 
 ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey); 
 var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

But i found always threw error :Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken

Comment: Have you tried to logout and login again to test this scenario?

Comment: just curious, why its throwing error like that and not getting a new token when the user is already authenticated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce your error. According to [this link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/pull/44) , it seems that code sample doesn't work when using  AcquireTokenSilentAsync(use NaiveSessionCache) , Please try to modify NaiveSessionCache.cs to [this](https://github.com/BarryWaluszko/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/0cf623a2956903de531bc20b2060764ce78ccdbc/WebAppGraphAPI/Utils/NaiveSessionCache.cs) .

Please let me know whether it helps .

Comment: i have a new question related to this code sample , please see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920678/how-can-i-get-refresh-token